# cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address at Infura

Tags: web3js, nodes, infura, nonce

i'm trying to call this function:

```
const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress)
```

On the testnet of this node:

```
'https://ropsten.infura.io/'
```

But I get this error on this node:

> cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address

```
at Object.InvalidResponse (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)

at RequestManager.send (../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)

at Eth.send [as getTransactionCount]
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your variable `myAddress`. It has to be represented as a hex string, even though it is actually a number. A hex string is a string, starting with `0x`. So your definition of `myAddress` should be something like

```
const myAddress= "0x....";
```

Comment: damm you are correct, so silly of me. thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks, my mistake was I passed an array instead of a string